# Regex to match a specific date format in JAVA

Tags: java, regex

I want to make sure a date is one of the following formats:

```
DD.MM.YYYY
DD-MM-YYYY
DD/MM/YYYY
```

My regex-pattern looks like this:

```
"^[0-9]{2}['/''-''.'][0-9]{2}['/''-''.'][1-9][0-9]${3}"
```

I thought this code above says:

1. -start by looking at numbers `0-9` (do this twice)
2. -followed by either `'/''-''.'`
3. -followed by `0-9` two more times.
4. -followed by either `'/''-''.'` (again)
5. End with a year (4 numbers) that start with 1

But it returns `false` on e.g. `16-10-1990`

I'm pretty new to regex, so any help on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Don't use regular expressions. Use a proper date parser.

Comment: looks like a type - `${3}` - i'm pretty sure it will never match ;)

Comment: `End with a year (4 numbers) that start with 1` - not correct as well. it's `not starts with zero` rather than `start with 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the corrected expression. I removed the single quotes from the character classes, escaped the dash and moved the "$" at the end.

```
^[0-9]{2}[/\-.][0-9]{2}[/\-.][1-9][0-9]{3}$
```

To ensure that the same character is used as a divider in both spaces, you can either do three OR-ed expressions:

```
^([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[1-9][0-9]{3}|[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[1-9][0-9]{3}|[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[1-9][0-9]{3})$
```

...or do a string replace on the '/', '-' and '.' characters so they're consistent (e.g. convert them all to dashes) before testing against the expression.

Comment: One thing I didn't think about: The way it's now it accepts e.g 16.10-1990 (. AND -). I want them to be the same type (either just . or / or -)

Comment: I tweaked the expression to satisfy that requirement. See new detail above.

Comment: Thanks. It was the same answer I came to as well. I was kinda hoping for a more neat solution though ;)

Comment: Last question; You add $ at the end only. Why not after each of the check you do (- / .)?

Comment: It's more concise and is arguably more maintainable in a small way. E.g. both of these are equivalent (checking for start/end string), but I prefer the first; ^(exp1|exp2|exp3)$ vs. (^exp1$)|(^exp2$)|(^exp3$).

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
^[0-9]{2}[-./][0-9]{2}[-./]1[0-9]{3}$
```

^ begin of string
2 digits
- or . or /
2 digits
- or . or /
1
3 digits
$ end of string

Comment: No !! The `|` char is considered as a literal inside a charachter class an NOT as an `or` operator. You shoul instead use groupping parentheses. ..